# TypeScript - how to: property starting with a "." (dot)

Tags: typescript

When calling a .NET OAuthToken Endpoint the result contains two properties starting with a ".":

```
{   
    "access_token":"abcde..."
    "expires_in":1209599
    ".expires":"Fri, 16 May 2014..."    <- this
    ".issued":"Fri, 02 May 2014..."     <- this
    ... more properties ...
}
```

What I like to do is create an interface in TypeScript to handle this result. However I do not know how to declare these two properties with the little dot in front.

```
export interface Token {
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    .expires???
    .issued???
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Viewing section 3.7.1 of [the TypeScript language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf), it looks like property signatures in object literals work about the same as object literal property definitions in JavaScript, meaning a property name can be an identifier, a string literal, or a numeric literal. In other words, you can simply do:

```
export interface Token {
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    ".expires": string;
    ".issued": string;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know it is THAT easy... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Accessing such properties works the same as it does in JavaScript, too, as pointed out in basarat's answer. You can't use `foo..expires` due to `.expires` not being a valid identifier.

Answer (score 6):

Just use quoted interface members :

```
interface Token {
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    '.expires': number;
}

var foo:Token;
foo['.expires'] = '123'; // Error 
foo['.expires'] = 123; // okay
```

Comment: Why are you typing `.expires` as a number when the example uses strings (technically string representations of timestamps, but nothing in the question says the timestamps are actually stored as numeric values)?

Comment: @JAB I wasn't focused on the particular type. Was focused on TypeSafety :)